# Update With duplicate key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one temp table **a** with idproduct and Qty like

```
idproduct    Qty
   123        2
   123        2
```

And anoth table **b** like

```
idproduct    stock
   123        10
```

Then i want to update (b.stock-a.qty)
So i want result like

```
idproduct    stock
   123        6
```

But it give me reult like

```
**idproduct    stock
    123        8**
```

From comment:

```
UPDATE INV
    SET INV.stock = isnull(INV.stock,0) - ISNULL(TEMP.QTY,0)
    FROM INVENTORY INV, #TempBagPack TEMP
    WHERE INV.idproduct = TEMP.idproduct
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please add your SQL statements. Also why does table a have rows with same idproduct? Is it not unique?

Comment: UPDATE INV SET INV.stock = isnull(INV.stock,0)  - ISNULL(TEMP.QTY,0)      
FROM INVENTORY INV , #TempBagPack TEMP
 WHERE INV.idproduct=TEMP.idproduct

Answer (score 0):

First. *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Second, your problem is that multiple rows match for the update, but SQL Server only updates the row once.  This is well documented.

The solution is to pre-aggregate the data:

```
update i
    set i.stock = coalesce(i.stock, 0) - coalesce(t.qty, 0)
    from inventory i join
         (select idproduct, sum(qty) as qty
          from #TempBagPack t
          group by idproduct
         ) t
         on i.idproduct = t.idproduct;
```

The warning in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) is:

> Use caution when specifying the FROM clause to provide the criteria
>   for the update operation. The results of an UPDATE statement are
>   undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not
>   specified in such a way that only one value is available for each
>   column occurrence that is updated, that is if the UPDATE statement is
>   not deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your query is clearly mentioned by @Gordon Linoff.

This is just another way of scripting using CTE.

```
     ;with cte_1
     As
     (select idproduct, sum(qty) as qty
      from #TempBagPack t
      group by idproduct
     ) 
     update i
    set i.stock = coalesce(i.stock, 0) - coalesce(t.qty, 0)
    from Cte_1 t
       Join inventory i
         on i.idproduct = t.idproduct;
```